# Nginx and unix user directories

Tags: unix, web-hosting, nginx

Is it possible to configure nginx so that domain/~user is proxied to a port set aside for that user.

Then the user can run another instance of nginx or unicorn on that port.

Is that possible? I would like a database which controls the user to port number relationship though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combination of `nginx` [`map`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMapModule) and `rewrite` modules. You would need a script to generate the map configuration out of the database, though.

The target configuration would look like this:

```
map $uri $new {
  default        http://www.domain.com/;
  include        /path/to/usermap.txt; 
}

server {
  server_name   www.domain.com;
  rewrite  ^    $new   redirect;
}
```

With `/path/to/usermap.txt` being generated by a script with an output similar to this:

```
# automatically generated by a script
/~alice          http://www.domain.com:8001/;
/~bob            http://www.domain.com:8002/;
/~chuck          http://www.domain.com:8003/;
```

Comment: is that like a c switch statement?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, are you referring to the example provided in the link to map documentation?

Comment: yes i meant the example in the document is mapping urls to folders? am i right? i could map ~users to sockets in the users home directory?

Comment: No, the example in the documentation is showing how to redirect different paths to different hosts.